# Not sure where to put data-backdrop='static'?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've copied some code to pop up a Bootstrap modal which works fine. However, I want to disable the background and from my research I need to add the `data-backdrop='static'` to my button. As far as I know I've done that correctly but it doesn't seem to be working.

The JS code is using modal.toggle to show the modal so I'm not sure where I would put it in the the JS code.

This is the code for my button:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DependentDetail", "Home", new { rid = item.RID })"
   class="modal-link btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-backdrop="static">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
    &nbsp;Verify
</a>
```

This is my JS code:

```
$(function () {
    // Attach modal-container bootstrap attributes to links with .modal-link class.
    // when a link is clicked with these attributes, bootstrap will display the href content in a modal dialog.
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    });

    // Attach listener to .modal-close-btn's so that when the button is pressed the modal dialog disappears
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
    });

    //clear modal cache, so that new content can be loaded
    $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });

    $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
    $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    $(this).attr('backdrop', 'true');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`data-backdrop` is used to Specify static for a `backdrop`, if you don’t want the modal to be closed when the user clicks outside of the modal.
and `backdrop`  Specifies whether the modal should have a dark overlay:

- true - dark overlay
- false - no overlay (transparent)

If you specify the value "static", it is not possible to close the modal when clicking outside of it

put this script inside your code, pass your modal id into it

```
$('#myModal').modal({
          backdrop: false
        });
```

Here is the snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal({backdrop: true});
    });
    $("#myBtn2").click(function(){
        $("#myModal2").modal({backdrop: false});
    });
    $("#myBtn3").click(function(){
        $("#myModal3").modal({backdrop: "static"});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Options</h2>
  <p>The backdrop option specifies whether the modal should have a dark overlay (the background color of the current page) or not.</p>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn">Modal with Overlay (backdrop:true)</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn2">Modal without Overlay (backdrop:false)</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" id="myBtn3">Modal with backdrop:"static"</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal with Dark Overlay</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This modal has a dark overlay.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal without Overlay</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This modal has no overlay.</p>
          <p><strong>Note:</strong> You cannot click outside of this modal to close it.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Static Backdrop</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>You cannot click outside of this modal to close it.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works in the code snippet so I just need to incorporate it into my existing jQuery. I added it as an "attr" like the data-target and data-toggle but that didn't seem to work. It will bring up the modal but the background did not change color. Look at my Updated code in the original post. Do you know where I would put the backdrop setting in the jQuery code I have?

Comment: $(this).attr('backdrop', 'true'); make it false