# Data model-toggle should dismiss only after click close button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here the data model should dismiss only after click cancel button .its data-dismisses when we click any side in screen .How to make this using Jquery /java script

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options clearly states how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery inside your onClick pass the modal id and do the following

```
    $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

Please find the code snippet below:

```js
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Small Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209246/not-sure-where-to-put-data-backdrop-static).

Answer (score 2):

Add data-backdrop property to your modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static>
```

Comment: thanks and how will use this in jquery or in jquery on click ? is this possible .

Comment: You're not using jquery and there's no need to if you use data-backdrop.  If you want to use jquery to open your modal, then use jquery and pass the option there - you *can't* use `data-` *and* jquery

Comment: It makes no sense to open the modal using data- attributes but change its properties using jquery.